# Did apple release graphics to make apps look like theirs?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I like how their email app looks so simple, with the background image with white/greyish vertical lines etc.

Is that image released or is it done programatically?

I remember there was a sample that they released that had some UI components, but I can't find it!

Comment: You're talking about Apple's iPhone email app? I don't see what you're seeing. Maybe a screenshot?

Comment: if you want a UI question answered, its probably best to post screens with, sense most people don't feel obligated to look up an app or etc. furthermore: i have no idea what lines you are talking about, and a staring at the mail app :)

Answer (score 4):

Most of Apple's standard UI comes default with their UIKit controls. For example, grouped table views look exactly like the ones you see in the Settings app, toolbars and navigation bars look exactly like those in Mail, text views behave like those in Notes, you get access to modal views that look and work identically to Mail and Messages, and so on.

When you open or create a nib file in Interface Builder, and drag UIKit elements to your interface, you'll see them just as Apple designed them. You'll get similar results even by creating them programmatically.

The sample code that shows off some UIKit controls is [UICatalog](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/UICatalog/Introduction/Intro.html).